# Append a suffix to heading of section, paragraph, etc. but omit when referencing

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing

I'd like to append a suffix to the heading of a subparagraph, which is defined as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {0.3\baselineskip \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {0.75ex plus 0.1ex}% space after heading
  {\normalfont\mdseries\itshape}}
```

So I thought the following modification could do it:

```
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1][]{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {0.3\baselineskip \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {0.75ex plus 0.1ex}% space after heading
  {\normalfont\mdseries\itshape #1}}
```

But as you can see, the suffix appears as a prefix:

[image]

Where do I need to place the placeholder `#1` to get the suffix behind the title? Or is it the wrong approach?
I also don't want the suffix to be included, when referenced by name, that is why I don't just include the suffix into the actual title.

Any hints?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1][]{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {0.3\baselineskip \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {0.75ex plus 0.1ex}% space after heading
  {\normalfont\mdseries\itshape #1}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\noindent AP \arabic{subsection}-\arabic{subparagraph}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subparagraph[MySuffix]{Hello World!}\label{subpar}

I also reference my subparagraph, but I don't want the suffix to be included: \ref{subpar}\quad\nameref{subpar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This can't work this way. You've forgotten moving arguments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Probably. I don't really understand how this whole macro works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds the suffix to the heading of the `\subparagraph`, but omits in `ToC` and in the `\nameref` command.

Prepending such suffixes in form of an optional first argument is not recommended and requires some `\if...` queries, appending is most times the better idea.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\latex@@subparagraph\subparagraph

\NewDocumentCommand{\subparagraphtitleformat}{mo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    #1 -- {\normalfont\textit{#2}}
  }{%
    #1%
  }%
}   

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subparagraph}{somo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@subparagraph{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@subparagraph[#2]{\subparagraphtitleformat{#3}[#4]}%
    }{%
      \latex@@subparagraph[#3]{\subparagraphtitleformat{#3}[#4]}%
    }%
  }%
}

}
\makeatother



\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 

%\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1][]{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
%  {0.3\baselineskip \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
%  {0.75ex plus 0.1ex}% space after heading
%  {\normalfont\mdseries\itshape #1}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\noindent AP \arabic{subsection}-\arabic{subparagraph}}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\subparagraph{Hello World!}[MySuffix]\label{subpar}

\subparagraph{Hello World Again!}\label{othersubpar}

I also reference my subparagraph, but I don't want the suffix to be included: \ref{subpar}\quad\nameref{subpar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, as I don't have a ToC I wondered if the solution would be even simpler, but it doesn't seem so, am I right? Thank you!

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Well, If you don't need a ToC, it can be simplified, of course

Answer (score 2):

A mild patch of `\@sect` can insert a suffix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {0.3\baselineskip \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {0.75ex plus 0.1ex}% space after heading
  {\normalfont\mdseries\itshape}}

\patchcmd{\@sect}{\@svsec{#8}}{\@svsec{#8 \csname suffix@title\endcsname}}{}{}

\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph

\subparagraph[*][<toc>]{<title>}[<suffix>]
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subparagraph}{somo}{{%
  \IfValueT{#4}{\def\suffix@title{#4}}% Suffix supplied
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsubparagraph*{#3}}% \subparagraph*
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsubparagraph[#2]{#3}}% \subparagraph[.]{..}
       {\oldsubparagraph{#3}}% \subparagraph{..}
    }%
}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{AP \arabic{subsection}-\arabic{subparagraph}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\paragraph{A paragraph}

\subparagraph{A subparagraph}[suffix]\label{spar:subpar}

\subparagraph{Another subparagraph}\label{spar:othersubpar}

I also reference my subparagraph, but I don't want the suffix to be included: \ref{spar:subpar}\quad\nameref{spar:subpar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I encountered various issues with your solution. First I needed to add also `\AtBeginDocument` like in the other answer, to get rid of occuring errors. Also the referencing does not work as desired. If you `nameref` the subparagraph then it references the preceding upper level title, in your case the `\paragraph`, in my real case I have a subsubsection before and it references that one. You can also see it in your screenshot. Thank you anyway!